# How do you integrate a flutter plugin into an existing flutter project?

Tags: flutter, plugins

I want to install a simple audio recorder which will record a user’s voice. I know I can find plugins on PubDev, however I have difficulty in integrating them into my Flutter project. I have installed ‘audio_recorder 1.0.2. in a new dart file as part of ‘lib’. I don’t know how to integrate this file into the flutter project. I have tried to a button in another dart file which when pressed would take the user to that file, without succes. ‘This class is not a widget’ is the message I get. The ‘GitHub’ version has the errors ‘undefined class’, ‘LocalFileSystem isn’t defined for the type ‘AudioRecorder’. The example version (why this difference?) has quite a few errors after installation. Dependencies and imports are ok. When I install audio_recorder 1.0.2 inside the project via ‘Dart packages’ I get a lot of errors. I have successfully installed an audio recorder in another android app. I would like some help in how to integrate plugins in a flutter project.

Answer (score 0):

The plugins have instructions on how to install it. Got to your pubspec.yaml-file and put it under dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you add your dependency to pubspec.yaml like this:
dependencies:
audio_recorder: ^1.0.2

After that make sure to type "flutter pub get" in console.

Go on a specified file in which you want to use Your dependency and import it like this:
import 'package:audio_recorder/audio_recorder.dart';

Comment: The 'specified file' you mentioned, does this mean a separate new page (route), in other words do I put in a new dart file or do I integrate it into an existing dart file? Do I simply copy the info in repository GitHub and can I paste just the way it is?

Comment: I have copied the example of audio_recorder 1.0.2. After having added the dependency and adding the permissions I try to run it and got two errors:Error: Could not resolve the package 'path_provider' in 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart'. and:Error: The method 'getApplicationDocumentsDirectory' isn't defined for the class 'AppBodyState'. What do I have to do?

Comment: make sure to run flutter pub get and flutter clean before running app